# GWT Emite , any experience?

Tags: gwt, frameworks

I am currentlty learning [gwt emite](http://code.google.com/p/emite/) for xmpp server communication using the GWT 
Should I go ahead with this or any other GWT framework exists ?

Please help.

Comment: depends what you want to do^^

Comment: i mean, should i go ahead with this framework or anything other i can do ?

Answer (score 0):

A google search reveals a couple of libraries

1. [GWT Bindings for the Strophe XMPP library](https://launchpad.net/gwt-strophe). This project intends to provide GWT bindings to the Strophe.js XMPP library
2. [Atmosphere-GWT project](http://code.google.com/p/atmosphere-gwt-comet/). Although not exactly a general purpose XMPP library, Atmosphere appears to have [some kind of support for XMPP](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/using-jquery-xmpp-and-atmosphere-to-cluster-your-websocketcomet-application/).